# In iOS, how do I set the position of the "Edit Menu" that appears above editable text?

Tags: ios, menu

[image: Apple calls the above menu the "Edit Menu"]

How do I control the position (above or below) for this edit menu?

Comment: How are you causing it to display?

Comment: It's being displayed when the user selects text in the UITextView.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798270/setting-uimenucontroller-arrow-direction-not-working

Comment: I appreciate the link maddy, but there is no usable example at that location and it only discusses how arrow direction may NOT be the way to set the position of this menu.